# Tableview content not scrolling on change of segmented control

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, uitableview

I have three different tableview cells each will be displayed as per the selected segmented control index but when the index is 1, in this the table viewcell has automatic dimensions (height), is unable to scroll at first but when i change the segmented control index and the table view reloads  after clicking on another index and then clicking back to 1 that tableview does scroll, but does not scroll when loaded initially or the first time when that index is clicked. The other 2 tableview cells have fixed height.

```
  @IBAction func changed(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
     setabs = seg.selectedSegmentIndex
    if setabs == 0 {
        cc = "gr"

    }else if setabs == 1 {
        cc = "sc"

    }else if setabs == 2 {
        cc = "us"
    }

   setab.reloadData()

}

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell : Tab?


    if cc == "gr" {

         setab.rowHeight = 82
           cell = self.setab.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cc!, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Tab


    cell!.label2.text = text1[indexPath.row]


    } else if cc == "sc" {



        setab.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        setab.estimatedRowHeight = 300

        cell = self.setab.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cc!, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Tab


    cell!.label2.text = text2[indexPath.row]



    } else if cc == "us" {

                    setab.rowHeight = 70

       cell = self.setab.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cc!,      forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Tab


    cell!.label3.text = text3[indexPath.row]


        }


    return cell!
}
```

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: @Adeel yes updated

Comment: I do not see any code relevant to scrolling the `tableView`. How many sections are there in your table? Are you implementing `heightForRowAtIndexPath`? And do you just want to scroll your `tableView` to a particular cell when the value of the `segmentedControl` changes?

Comment: @Adeel there is only one sections. no im not implementing height for row at index path. i do not want to scroll to a particular cell when my segmented control changes, the entire table changes when with that particular custom cell and its content also changes when i press the segmented control. the number of rows in the tableview is also the array count according to the values of "cc".

Comment: I suggest that you should show your complete code. I'm unable to figure out the reason based on the information you have provided.

Comment: @Adeel as seen from the code i have provided when the segmented control changes the table is reloaded and the content in the tableview changes according to the value of "cc" (the variable in the code). when cc = "sc" as seen from the code which has automatic dimension, scrolling does not happen initially it happens after i change the segmented control and go back to "sc". Rest of the code has nothing more than this. Also the table is displayed fine scrolling happens when cc != "sc" but when cc == "sc" it doesnt scroll below until segmented control is changed back and again.

Comment: There seems to be no problem in your code. I can give only one suggestion. Move `setab.rowHeight = xx` to `numberOfRowsInSection`. And you probably don't need `estimatedRowHeight = 300` too.